# Do any major E-commerce Companies have Modals in their Checkout Process?

Tags: e-commerce, modal-windows, checkout, conversion, modal

Are the examples of **major e-commerce** companies using a **`Modal`** in their ***checkout* process**?

Thinking companies like: `Amazon` `AliExpress`, `eBay`, `etsy`, `Flipkart`, `Groupon`, `Rakuten`, `TaoBao`, `Walmart`, `Wayfair`, etc.

Trying to understand if `Modals` are considered "***Good* UX**" by collecting **`data`** on what the biggest e-commerce companies - who have the most to lose in terms of *conversion* - when it comes to UX in *practice*.

Not looking for a theoretical answer/discussion, but rather to understand if anyone has seen a `Modal` in practice on a major ecommerce site during ***checkout***.

> **Note**: Apologies if this is not the "right" place for this question, if there is a better place for it, please share! Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...curious, what do you propose is the benefit of using modals in a shopping cart checkout process?

Comment: There are several use cases where major sites use modals in check-out flows, such as updating a payment method. What is the question that you are trying to solve with examples?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Trying to find cases in the real world of `Modal` being used in the most important step in e-commerce; the checkout process. I often see `Modals` used in situations where they don't make _any_ sense and want to understand what companies with a _lot_ at stake and big A/B-testing budgets do in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, modals are website-based UI components that I have seen rarely on Shien and Rakuten as a confirmation to process the order and payment. They aren't much help but definitely serve as a final reminder to the user about the payment.

Comment: Hi @Anshika, thanks for your answer. Very curious where you have seen modals on `Shien` and `Rakuten` in the checkout process ... we haven't seen them on either of these e-commerce sites ... ‍♂️